# The string was not recognized as a valid uri

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

When I run my method I get the error:

> System.ArgmentException: The string was not recognized as a valid uri

```
private void loadXMLBttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog selectConfigFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    selectConfigFile.Title = "Select an existing XML config file...";
    selectConfigFile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    selectConfigFile.DefaultExt = ".xml";
    selectConfigFile.Filter = "xml files|.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    var selectedFile = selectConfigFile.SafeFileName;
    selectConfigFile.ShowDialog();
    XDocument configFile = XDocument.Load(selectedFile);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that you set the selectedFile before you show the dialog. The problem could be resolved 100% if you will rewrite the code to this way:

```
private void loadXMLBttn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog selectConfigFile = new OpenFileDialog()
    {
        Title = "Select an existing XML config file...",
        InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
        DefaultExt = "*.xml",
        Filter = "XML files|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    };
    if (selectConfigFile.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        var selectedFile = selectConfigFile.FileName;
        XDocument configFile = XDocument.Load(selectedFile);
    }
}
```

This will fix a filter, which doesn't work in your example and it makes the file dialog options initializer more clear. Also if the user wouldn't select any file - it wouldn't try to load empty string path

Comment: I tried your example but I'm getting an error where Syste.IO.FileNotFoundException is showing up. It looks like its not selecting the file correctly and trying to load from my Visual Studio repo.

Comment: @TomD, I have updated the answer, replaced SafeFileName with FileName. Because SafeFileName contains only a name without full path

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this exception because your `selectedFile` variable is never really populated.

You need to populate the `selectedFile` variable **After** showing the dialog and allowing the user to select the XML file:

```
selectConfigFile.ShowDialog();
var selectedFile = selectConfigFile.SafeFileName;
XDocument configFile = XDocument.Load(selectedFile);
```

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks